# Propensity score matching - within subsample analysis

Tags: regression, propensity-scores, matching

I am trying to understand the impact of a graduate degree in mathematics on the wages of students compared to other degrees. I have been running a probability score matching model using a logarithm regression to estimate the propensity score and then following with a NN matching algorithm (1 to 5) with different calipers, where treatment is a graduate degree in mathematics. I utilize various controls: gender, SAT scores, grades in school, parents education, parents income, etc. and I get fairly good matching (both support is ok and standardized bias too)

Given I am also interested in possible gender differences, I estimate the same propensity score matching model on two subsamples (male subsample and female subsample).

I get the following results:

- ATT on total sample = $0.08$ (significant at $1$%)
- ATT on the female sample = $0.07$ (significant at $1$%)
- ATT on the male sample = $0.04$ (not significant)

It is peculiar to me that the ATT in the male subsample is not significant, whilst instead the ATT is significant in the overall sample. This is peculiar to me since I have used gender as a variable when estimating my propensity score in the overall sample!

How can I explain the fact that, in the overall sample I have a significant ATT on wages and in the male subsample I do not? Does it mean that my ATT estimate on the overall sample has no valid interpretation? In other words, how can I interpret the different coefficients?

Comment: First you say you are interested in gender differences, then you say that you can't explain those differences and find them peculiar.   What's so peculiar? The effect was much smaller in men than in women.  What is a little peculiar is that the effect was smaller in both men and women than in the total sample.   But significance differences aren't surprising at all, as clearly the samples were different sizes.

Comment: But what would the interpretation of the coefficient on the overall sample be? Impact of a mathematics degree, regardless of gender?

Comment: How are you taking the correlation structure due to matching into account?  I assume you are using efficient matching, i.e., a control can match more than one case.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Are you matching and estimating the ATT separately for the male/female estimates?  How many females are in the sample?

Comment: Hey @DemetriPananos, yes I am using with replacement (so a control can match more than one treated individual). Anyways:
Female sample: I have 515 treated individuals and 1071 matched controls for the female sample
Male sample: 879 treated individuals and 1071 matched controls
Overall sample: 1409 treated individuals and 1889 matched controls

Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: @PeterFlom, I am not 100% sure what you are saying is correct. When estimating the ATT for the overall sample, I used gender in the logistic regression to estimate the propensity score - which would thus mean I am controlling for gender. 
This is where my confusion stems from. I would expect the results on the gender subsamples to be in line with those of the overall sample. What do you think? Anyways, thanks for your help!

Comment: @FrankHarrell, Hello! Yes I am using matching with replacement, thus a control can match more than one treated individual!

Comment: No, there is no reason that controlling for gender would mean that the subsamples would be similar to the main sample.  Indeed, if the subsamples were similar to the main, then there would be little need to control for it.

Comment: Matching with replacement is the efficient way to do matching (if you must use matching, which is seldom the best approach - see https://hbiostat.org/bbr/propensity).  But it induces a complex irregular correlation structure in the data that must be handled with procedures such as the cluster bootstrap.  How did you handle the correlation structure?

Comment: @FrankHarrell I bootstrapped my results over 150 reps in order to obtain the ATT for the three subsamples!

Comment: Can you please explain your abbrevs (like ATT???), as an edit to the post?